# Why does the test command need escaping for ">"?

Tags: bash, syntax

From `$ help test`:

> test: test [expr]
>
> Evaluate conditional expression.
>
> Exits with a status of 0 (true) or 1 (false) depending on
>   the evaluation of EXPR.  Expressions may be unary or binary.  Unary
>   expressions are often used to examine the status of a file.  There
>   are string operators and numeric comparison operators as well.

I'm a bit confused as to what `expr` can supposedly contain. The help page for `test` indicates that it is a conditional expression, consisting of file, string or numeric operators. So how does the string comparison operator cause unwanted file re-direction?

```
$ [ "a" > "b" ]
$ ls -la 
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user     0 May 28 17:22 b
```

I understand that to prevent re-direction I need to escape `>`, but I'm confused *why*. It's not like I can place any command as the `expr`:

```
$ [ echo "hello" ] 
bash: [: echo: unary operator expected
```

As far as I can make out from the help text `test` only evaluates pre-defined operators in `expr` - [file re-direction not being one of them](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html). `test`/`[` are only meant to evaluate conditional expressions - I'm limited to only the operators that `test` accepts, and arguments it accepts with them.

(For comparison, with the following built-in there is no confusion as to what `>` means and no escaping is necessary):

```
$ echo $[2>1]
1
```

So what is interpreting `>` as re-direction meaning escaping is needed?

Comment: My bash man page says: `The old format $[expression] is deprecated and will be removed in upcoming versions of bash.` Use `$((...))` instead

Comment: Which man page is that? It's not even in the 3.2 man page on macOS, dated 2008.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`test` is an ordinary command, not special syntax, and as such undergoes the same processing as any other command.

```
[ "a" > "b" ]
```

is just a (overly) clever synonym for

```
test "a" > "b"
```

and so `>` is interpreted as an output redirection before the arguments to `test` are identified. The exact same command can be written

```
[ "a" ] > "b"
```

To prevent the shell from recognizing `>` as the redirection operator, it must be escaped.

```
[ "a" \> "b" ]  # or [ "a" ">" "b" ]
```

The other example you gave, `$[2>1]` *is* special syntax (not simply a built-in command), and so doesn't undergo the same processing. `$[...]` is an obsolete, no-longer-documented, form of arithmetic expansion, equivalent to `$((2>1))`. As special syntax, the shell parses the contents of `$[...]` different than it would an ordinary command.

---

A note on `]`. `test` is a regular command, and so is responsible for interpreting its arguments as it sees fit. The following are all *syntactically* correct:

1. `test a \> b`
2. `test a \> b ]`
3. `[ a \> b`
4. `[ a \> b ]`

However, only 1 and 4 are *semantically* correct. When used as `[`, the final argument *must* be `]` to maintain the illusion of `[ ... ]` as merely "grouping" the expression.

```
$ [ a \> b
bash: [: missing `]'
```

When used as `test`, `]` is not a valid part of an expression at all, and must be omitted.

```
$ test a \> b ]
bash: test: too many arguments
```